# Compare objects from more than 2 lists

Tags: python, collections, comparison, combinations, equals

Is there a way to compare all 2-item combinations of more than 2 lists?

Let's say there is an object:

```
class obj():
   def __init__():
       self.name = # some name
       self.number = random(10)
   def equals(obj):
       if self.number == obj.number:
           return True
       else: return False
```

`list1,list2,list3....listX` - all these lists contain instances of class `obj`

I want to compare all 2-item combinations from these lists and return equal objects.

So if there is an `obj` in `list2` which `obj.number` attribute is 5 and `obj` in `list8` which has `obj.number` 5, it will be returned.

For two lists the comparison would be simple:

```
   for obj1 in list1:
      for obj2 in list2:
          if obj1.equals(obj2):
               print obj1,obj2
```

But I don't know how to make this comparison for more lists of objects.
Do you have any advice?

Comment: `itertools.permutations` may help but I don't have much experiences with it. Why do you want this?

Comment: @DavidMašek I'm working on program which compares bookmakers. So each of those lists is one bookmaker. I want to compare bids of equal matches.

Comment: first I would replace the `equals` method with `def __eq__(self, other):
if isinstance(other, self.__class__): return self.number == other.number  else: return False` to allow comparing objects natively

Comment: actually, first I would declare the class as `class Obj(object):`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you might know, with X lists, the time complexity will go up to O(n^X), which is far from optimal (in the case that all lists have the same length =n)

Now it all depends on what you actually want as output. It seems to me that you want to find objects that are present in multiple lists.

One way to do this in a more performant way is to use a dictionary (hashmap) and iterate trough every list. Hash objects based on their `self.number`.

This will result in something like: `{1: [obj1], 2: [obj2, obj3], 3: [obj4], ...}`, where the keys are the numbers of the objects and the values are the objects that have these values as number.

By running over this dictionary and only considering entries that have a list with a size larger or equal than 2, you will end up with the objects that are equal.

here the time complexity is equal to the O(n*X), which is ~ O(n)

---

To illustrate this, I've created a short simple **example** that uses 2 lists:

```
from collections import defaultdict

class Obj():
   def __init__(self, value):
       self.number = value


def find_equals(list1,list2):
    d = defaultdict(list)
    for obj1 in list1:
        d[obj1.number].append(obj1)
    for obj2 in list2:
        d[obj2.number].append(obj2)
    return [d[i] for i in d if len(d[i]) >= 2]

def test():
    l1 = [Obj(1),Obj(2),Obj(3),Obj(4)]
    l2 = [Obj(5),Obj(2),Obj(3),Obj(6)]
    print find_equals(l1,l2)
test()
```

It can probably be optimised with nifty python constructs, but it shows the idea behind it.

The **output** is:

```
[[<__main__.Obj instance at 0x103278440>, <__main__.Obj instance at 0x103278560>], [<__main__.Obj instance at 0x103278488>, <__main__.Obj instance at 0x1032785a8>]]
```

Which are the objects with the numbers `2` and `3`, that were used in the test sample.

Comment: please explain what the keys and values are. It's not clear

Comment: Didn't the line  "Hash objects based on their self.number." explain that? Obviously the `self.number` would be key and  objects would end up as values. When the key is already present in the dictionary, the object is added to the key. Anyway I tried to make it a bit more clearer.

Comment: I've added a code example to give a better idea of the sketched approach.

Comment: excellent, thank you. Good solution. a) call `dict` something else. b) there is no need to use `in dict.keys()`, just use `in dict`. c) if you make the dictionary a `d = collections.defaultdict(list)`, you can avoid the `if obj in dict: append else set` and just do `dict[obj.number].append(obj)`. d) if the lists are stored in a list/tuple, you can make it work for n lists, not just two, I think it's a fair assumption to make :)

Comment: Thanks for the great advice, I've updated the answer accordingly. I've left the support for multiple lists for OP. Goodluck with it!

Answer (score 1):

A (very) simple approach would be to get the intersection of the lists of objects.
To do that, you have to make your object hashable, to build a set for each list of objects.

```
def __hash__(self):
    return self.number
```

Then, to check multiple lists, you simply take the set intersection:

```
x = [Obj(1) Obj(3) Obj(8) Obj(10) Obj(3)] 
y = [Obj(2) Obj(9) Obj(10) Obj(3)] 

intersection = x & y  # -> returns {Obj(3), Obj(10)}
```

This implementation has worst case complexity `(n - 1) * O(L)`, where L is the maximum of the set lengths and n is the number of sets. 
So, in terms of complexity, I think DJanssens's answer is faster.

But if performance is not the problem (e.g. you have small lists etc.), I think it's way more elegant to be able to write:

```
def intersect(*lists):
     return set.intersection(*map(set, lists))
```

or the same thing in lambda notation:

```
intersect = lambda *lists: set.intersection(*map(set, lists))
```